# Django Web Server is not opening open source project

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I'm trying to run the Django medicine web-app. it's an open-source project. here's the link https://github.com/jai-singhal/croma when I run this command python manage.py runserver 
I got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qndj.png)

Comment: Consider opening an issue on the github repository for this code. It is highly unlikely that someone here will be familiar enough with the package to give you useful help quickly, but the maintainer of the project should be able to help you out.

Comment: ok, I Understand that! but do you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run CMD with the permissions system administrator.
https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/